# Issue authorizing access with google analytics super proxy

Tags: google-app-engine, proxy, google-analytics, authorization

I'm setting up google analytics super proxy to create some public queries on my google analytics data. I have followed the instructions given in the below link to setup a analytics super proxy in app engine:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-super-proxy

I have followed the steps specified, enabling access for analytics api and creating a client ID for the super proxy web application deployed in app engine. I updated the required properties in the app.yaml and config.py files in the super proxy and deployed it to app engine.

I'm able to open the admin page of the deployed super proxy, but when I try to authorize access, I get the an error saying 'invalid_client' (although the client id seems to match with the one I created in developer console):

[image]

I'm unable to figure out what has gone wrong, or if I've missed something? Can you please help?

Regards,
Anand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the [Dev Console](https://console.developers.google.com) -> Your Project -> APIs & auth -> Consent screen. Make sure all the non optional fields are filed in (specifically in your case PRODUCT NAME).